# Generate a custom path from XML tags with attribute and value in java

Tags: java, xml, xslt, xpath

I need a Java program to generate path for each tag value including the attributes also in path. Need to generate path even if the value is empty.

**My sample XML file**

```
<root>
    <elemA>one</elemA>
    <elemA attribute1='first' attribute2='second'>two</elemA>
    <elemB>three</elemB>
    <elemA>four</elemA>
    <elemC>
        <elemB>five</elemB>
    </elemC>
    <elemD/>
</root>
```

My Goal is to produce the following output

```
//root[1]/elemA[1]='one'
//root[1]/elemA[2][@attribute1='first' and attribute2='second']='two'
//root[1]/elemB[1]='three'
//root[1]/elemA[3]='four'
//root[1]/elemC[1]/elemB[1]='five'
//root[1]/elemD[1]=
```

I need this to compare two XML files generated from different tools and create a comparison result. I used XMLUnit but it is having false positives if the elements are repeated twice or more (Arrays) in different orders

Comment: The predicate `@attribute1='first',attribute2='second` in `//root[1]/elemA[2][@attribute1='first',attribute2='second']` would give a syntax error in XPath 1 and a probably a run-time error about the effective boolean value not being defined for a sequence of more than one item in XPath 2 and later. So I guess you want `@attribute1='first' and attribute2='second'` instead

Comment: @MartinHonnen thanks for pointing out the mistake. updated my question